# GDB: How to find 'passphrase' at $eax when address out of bounds?

Tags: c, debugging, passwords, gdb

I have the output here when I disas in GDB the function that pertains to comparing the program input to a 'passphrase'. I know the real 'passphrase' is in $eax, but when I try to examine $eax, I get the error that the address is out of bounds. What can I do to examine $eax?

```
Dump of assembler code for function s:
   0x08048444 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x08048445 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048447 <+3>:     mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   0x0804844a <+6>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0804844f <+11>:    cmpb   $0x0,(%edx)
   0x08048452 <+14>:    je     0x804845d <s+25>
   0x08048454 <+16>:    add    $0x1,%eax
=> 0x08048457 <+19>:    cmpb   $0x0,(%edx,%eax,1)
   0x0804845b <+23>:    jne    0x8048454 <s+16>
   0x0804845d <+25>:    pop    %ebp
   0x0804845e <+26>:    ret
```

Comment: You mean you're using `x $edx`?  What does `p $edx` say?

Comment: Oops, rewriting the question. Sorry about that. The question is actually about $eax.

Comment: and I am using x $eax. It gives me this output:
`0x1:     <Address 0x1 out of bounds>`

Comment: If the value of `$eax` is just 1, wouldn't that imply that `$eax` does not, in fact, contain a pointer to the passphrase?

Comment: yea, I thought that also... But what is cmpb comparing when `cmpb    $0x0, (%edx, $eax,1)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
cmpb $0x0,(%edx,%eax,1)
```

Means "compare `0` to the byte at `edx + eax * 1`".

You need to look at edx (`p/x $edx`) *and* eax (`p/x $eax`) to see what byte you're addressing.

Comment: Not only is %edx used as the base register in the SIB byte, but %eax is explicitly set to 0 at the start of the function, while %edx receives the function argument:`0x08048447 <+3>:     mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx;   
   0x0804844a <+6>:     mov    $0x0,%eax`.

Answer (score 1):

The passphrase is in **EDX** instead of **EAX**. So you'd want to run

```
(gdb) p (char*)$edx
```

to see the content of the null terminated string.

You can tell that you want **EDX** because the code moves the first argument of the function into it:

```
0x08048447 <+3>:     mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
```

and because **EAX** is used as an index. It was first set to 0, then incremented by 1 in a loop:

```
0x0804844a <+6>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
<...>
0x08048454 <+16>:    add    $0x1,%eax
0x08048457 <+19>:    cmpb   $0x0,(%edx,%eax,1)
0x0804845b <+23>:    jne    0x8048454 <s+16>
```

Note how after comparing `(%edx,%eax,1)` to 0 the code jumps back to increment **EAX**.